# Change openpyxl Excel Worksheet to Landscape Orientation

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried and failed for longer than I care to admit.  I have read the documentation.  Stumped.  Any guidance greatly appreciated!!! Thanks...Ellie The Good Dog

This block is OK:

```
import openpyxl
myexcel = openpyxl.Workbook()
mysheet = myexcel.active
mysheet['A1'] = 'Test'
mysheet.print_area = 'A1:Z1'
myexcel.save(r'C:\Temp\Testing.xlsx')
```

This block fails:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet import page
mysheet.page.orientation = 'landscape'
mysheet.orientation = 'landscape'
mysheet.worksheet.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 'landscape'
mysheet.worksheet.page.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 'landscape'
mysheet.worksheet.ORIENTATION = 'landscape'
mysheet.worksheet.page.ORIENTATION = 'landscape'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to change the printer settings:

```
openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.set_printer_settings(worksheetObject, paper_size = <someInt>, orientation='landscape')
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that does it!  I don't know if this is good or bad form, but I am also stumped on how to fit the printing to 1 page wide.  Any ideas?  These do not work - thanks!  Marc :mysheet.page.PrintPageSetup(fitToWidth=1)
mysheet.PrintPageSetup(fitToWidth=1)

Comment: Found the answer to my second question: mysheet.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
mysheet.page_setup.fitToHeight = False

Comment: great! thanks to share it, it is good to have all this information in the same place